# Iterate {{#each }} certain times in HandlebarsJS

Tags: handlebars.js

I have below code in HandlebarsJS.

```
   <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each this.attr_name}}
                {{#if @index < 9}}
                    <th>{{ this }}</th>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

But this line `{{#if @index < 5}}` is not working. I would like to iterate `{{#each` 8 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars does not have any built-in way to do comparison logic like `@index < 9`. You will need to create your own [custom helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers) to do that.

Fortunately, your problem can be solved with a very simple helper.

For example, implement the `@index < 9` comparison, you could create a helper that takes some number `num` and a comparison number `comparator` and returns `true` if `num < comparator` or else `false`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('lessThan', (num, comparator) => num < comparator);
```

To implement this helper in your template:

```
{{#each this.attr_name}}
  {{#if (lessThan @index 8)}}
    <th>{{ this }}</th>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Note: We are using `8` as the `comparator` argument instead of `9` because your question said you want eight items outputted and `@index` is 0-based, so: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 is eight items.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wja8n1k0/) is an example fiddle.

An alternative approach would be to create a helper that takes an array and a `count` and returns the first `count` number of items in that array:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('first', (arr, count) => arr.slice(0, count));
```

Using this helper in your template would simplify it to:

```
{{#each (first this.attr_name 8)}}
  <th>{{ this }}</th>
{{/each}}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vxc5ob0k/) is a fiddle demonstrating this approach.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working like Magic. Thanks.